# Non recognition of string when referred as list element

Tags: python

I need to check which elements of the first list appear in the second one.

First at all I create both lists by adding the elements,

```
my_file = open("/nfs/pic.es/user/c/cperez/pnfsid_type2_unclassified.txt", "r")
with open('/nfs/pic.es/user/c/cperez/pnfsid_type2_unclassified_short.txt') as f:
    unclassified = f.read().splitlines()

fullpaths = open("/nfs/pic.es/user/c/cperez/path_oct_nov.out", "r")
with open('/nfs/pic.es/user/c/cperez/path_oct_nov.out') as f2:
    full_paths = f2.read().splitlines()
```

Then, I run all over 'full_paths' indices in order to check if the element 'unclassified[4]' (str type) is in 'full_paths'

```
N=len(unclassified)
M=len(full_paths)

print(unclassified[4])
```

Output:

```
 SusyAnalysis
```

If I refer it as a list element it gives no match,

```
for j in range(0,M):
    if unclassified[4] in full_paths[j]:
        print(i,j,'yes')
```

But referring it as the string it is 'SusyAnalysis', works correctly,

```
print(unclassified[4])

for j in range(0,M):
    if 'SusyAnalysis' in full_paths[j]:
        print(i,j,'yes')
```

Output:

```
  SusyAnalysis
0 658062 yes
0 759090 yes
0 989630 yes
0 1004369 yes
0 1236539 yes
0 1421179 yes
```

I suspect the main problem is in the blank space between the strings in the main unclassified list

```
['  zabai.bde389f10d8fd3aed35fae28c5265f4b9505fab2', '  crab_92X_newL1_RegForVBF_ThreeJets_allTauCombinations_HLTPhysics1', '  CITo2Mu_M2000_CUETP8M1_Lam16TeVConLL_13TeV_Pythia8_Corrected-v3', '  2018-06-19_DevTools_80X_Hpp_v1', '  SusyAnalysis', '  ZprimeToBBbar_M_2500', '  monoZ_2016_data_two_Lepton_final', '  XeXe2017_default_98_4', '  memOutput_CarmenTrial4_28Aug2017', '  v6_SM']
```

why is it not recognised as string list element? Or is related with blank spaces between the list elements?

Comment: You have an additional unrelated error. You are opening the files twice. Please remove the lines before the `with` statements as they are not being used nor closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the whitespace within the string, `'  SusyAnalysis'` is not the same as `'SusyAnalysis'`. To fix this, you can strip the list item in the if statement:

```
for j in range(0,M):
    if unclassified[4].strip() in full_paths[j]:
        print(i,j,'yes')
```